# Creating a bootstrap dark theme without duplicating CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up my SCSS dark theme to be as maintainable as possible.

In Bootstrap 5 you can set the `data-bs-theme='dark'` property on your HTML body tag, to either light or dark, and bootstrap will handle the rest.

This works ok but it requires me to set all of their colour classes inline, like `<nav class="bg-body">`.  I’d prefer not to have tons of CSS classes added to my HTML like this though, so I'm trying to use bootstrap variables in my SCSS files instead.

The only issue with this is that it ends up in the sort of duplication of code like below:-

```
nav {
  background-color: $body-bg;
}

@include color-mode(dark) {
  nav {
    background-color: $body-bg-dark;
  }
}
```

I then thought I could just have a separate file with something like this:-

```
// Variable overrides for dark theme

@include color-mode(dark) {
  $body-bg: #1a1a1a;
}
```

So I can override those variables in a single place for dark mode, rather than the previous code, but this doesn’t seem to work, I think due to lexical scoping.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?  I only really need a dark mode right now, as the default - but I want in the future to just be able to define light mode colours in a single place, to make the switch easy.

Maybe I'm approaching this incorrectly so if anyone has any pointers on how best to organise my CSS I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS variables instead...

```
@import "variables";
@import "variables-dark";

[data-bs-theme="dark"] {
  --bs-body-bg: #1a1a1a;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/UthuqoCWiH